# Floating point number precision for different return types

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, precision, plpgsql, pgadmin

I am writing a Postgres function in which I select calculation results with double precision into a table type. When looking at the results for values which can't be represented as binary, one can see the limited precision when calling the function from the IntelliJ IDEA database console, but not in pgAdmin.

To illustrate what I am doing, consider the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    mycol double precision
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFn() RETURNS mytable AS $$
DECLARE
  myvar mytable;
BEGIN
  SELECT 0.3::DOUBLE PRECISION INTO myvar.mycol;
  return myvar;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT myFn();
```

As mentioned before, in IntelliJ I get the result (0.299999999999999989) whereas in pgAdmin I get (0.3).

I suspect, that this is only a difference in displaying the value, as 0.3 can't be represented in binary, and therefore is not stored exactly in the database.

But now comes the strange part: when I insert a row into the database and select it again I get 0.3 in both applications.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (0.3);
SELECT mycol FROM mytable;
```

Also, if I don't store the value in a table type within the function, but in a variable directly, I again get 0.3 in both applications:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFn() RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION AS $$
DECLARE
  myvar DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
  SELECT 0.3 INTO myvar;
  return myvar;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: For a fair comparison you would have to call the first function with `SELECT (myFn()).mycol;` Else you add the composite type wrapper - hence `(0.3)`, and not `0.3`. Which also leads me to the conclusion that  IntelliJ IDEA (I got no experience with that) does some casting and / or rounding of its own when confronted with composite types.

Answer (score 1):

The value 0.3 cannot be stored exactly as `double precision`, because the IEEE standard stores floating point values in binary representation.

You do not normally notice that in PostgreSQL, because it rounds away the last three digits which may contain errors.

You can show all digits by setting `extra_float_digits` to 3.

```
SET extra_float_digits=3;
SELECT 0.3::double precision;

┌──────────────────────┐
│        float8        │
├──────────────────────┤
│ 0.299999999999999989 │
└──────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

I don't know how IntelliJ IDEA formats and displays double precision values, but maybe it sometimes does its own rounding or converts the values to `numeric` first, which also rounds away these extra digits.

However, you should not worry about that. If you use `double precision`, you are in for a certain amount of imprecision.